# Shadowrun Road Trip

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, shadowrun, travel

So I've been in a Shadowrun campaign and my group has fallen afoul of both Aztechnology and some powerful Seattle organized crime people. I've been scouring all the books I can think of, but I can't find anything on travel in Shadowrun; even the Sixth World Almanac doesn't say anything about border crossings, and it's bothering me a little.

For instance, my character has a criminal SIN, but only because he didn't have any ID at all (it was lost in the Crash, and he's also an amnesiac so he can't go and dig up the old records). However, his criminal record is spotless, in part due to paranoid identity hiding and in part due to common sense and the Erased quality.

Would he have issues getting to, say, Denver through Salish Sidhe and PCC/Sioux lands? Or, more coherently, are there any rules that govern this? It would be in his character to take his upgraded RV (that may or may not exist, again, paranoia) through the desert rather than leave it in Seattle, so any way he takes of getting there has to permit a Ford-Canada Buffalo on a 20k budget.

We're playing Fourth Edition, but I remember having this same problem back in Third as well.

Comment: Doesn't having a criminal SIN that has been completely cleaned mean that he now has a regular SIN? Furthermore, is anything preventing him from acquiring a fake SIN?

Comment: The book's somewhat incoherent on this one. Technically, Criminal SIN means criminal record, but it is the only form of ID that the character has I figured he'd keep it, just not his criminal record. Since he's an amnesiac former squatter, I figure he'd probably been booked on something before being released (vagrancy?).

I'd prefer not to use a fake SIN to travel, since that means each border crossing becomes a nightmare, and also potentially a felony.

Comment: Found some stuff in this: http://www.shadowrun4.com/wp-content/uploads/Downloads/SRM02-25A_Done_Deal.pdf

Not what I'm looking for exactly, but they do have rules for crossing the borders inside Denver. These are presented in a fake SIN format, however, not in terms of a legitimate one (though a criminal SIN may also earn scrutiny at a border crossing).

Comment: Well, I remember seeing info in the Sixth World Almanac, but mainly in the fluff (Jackpointers discussing how to pass borders). Are you looking for actual rules (which yes, can be [surprisingly absent in some important areas](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/17081/are-there-glider-rules-in-shadowrun-4e) ), or for fluff based answers?

Comment: I'll take both, but I'd prefer actual rules-my GM tends to take the worst possible interpretation of any fluff.

Comment: Also, a quick search of the Sixth World Almanac didn't do much to actually answer my questions, but my PDF reader was being weird, and I'm not exactly sure if a search for "borders" will hit what I'm looking for.

Comment: It looks like someone at Catalyst reads RPG Stack Exchange. They've just released Coyotes, a 5th edition sourcebook that covers border crossings: http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/123829

Comment: Read it already. Still not sure what to think about it.

Comment: Does the supplement answer your question, but in a less than satisfactory way?

Comment: It doesn't really touch on stuff outside organized border crossings, but it allows a good way to roleplay it. Part of my gripe with it is that it looks more at the structure of the border crossing than, for instance, the process of spoofing past with a SIN, but that's covered elsewhere and is sorta mentioned here. It doesn't really look at all the legal distinctions of the "who can go where", but it briefly touches on it (and covers the Seattle/Salish border).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Runner's Companion*: “Travel and Smuggling” (pp. 28–33) has an overview of the subject but no hard numbers. It discusses common transportation methods, techniques, and challenges that players are likely to face.

The *Unfriendly Skies* and *Deadly Waves* mini-supplements are full of vehicle stats, which may come in handy for travel adventures.

*Spy Games*: “Getting Around in Denver” (pp. 13–16) briefly discusses border crossings, although the gist is that the internal borders are a joke that only stop honest people. There's more information in *Midnight.*

For more extensive examples of world travel and border crossing, see the *Dawn of the Artifacts* series. Each adventure features at least one sprawl and one feral zone in a different part of the world. There are guidelines for travel by car, rail, air, space, smuggler, and coyote. Shadowrun has a long history of introducing optional rules and setting details in adventure books like this.

*Dusk*: This adventure mostly sweeps travel details under the rug, although it does have some stats for third-world airport security and a bush pilot (p. 14).

*Midnight*: “Road Trip!” (pp. 22–25) has stats and mini-encounters for traveling cross-country with a T-bird smuggler. “Denver Layover” (pp. 25–29) deals with border crossing with write-ups for a fixer, coyote, and border patrol. There's also a piece on traveling through snowy Chicago, but it wouldn't generalize well to other locations.

*Darkest Hour*: “Travel on the Fly” and “Travel Arrangements” (pp. 10–13) has the most technical information on travel, with comparisons of commercial air, sub-orbital, road, and train, including checkpoints and security ratings. “To Find a Thief” (pp. 21–30) has extensive information about a holding center and jailbreak, which is not directly related to travel, but useful if the runners get themselves in hot water with the travel authorities.

*New Dawn*: There are scenes aboard a zeppelin and a cargo ship, but they may not generalize well to other missions.

Comment: Do they work for everything, or just those individual places?

Dusk doesn't seem to have anything along the lines of what I was looking for (I already had it; I have this thing where I always think I'm gonna run a pre-made adventure and then never do; since I'm a GM of 4th Ed. myself), and I'm loathe to spend money on another adventure I probably won't wind up using; I could probably find it at the local game store or second-hand bookstore, but I hate reading a book for something then putting it back without buying it. Or I could just get it on RPGNow, but I'd likely be buying it for one rule.

Comment: Also (and my previous comment was right at length limit or I'd put it there), a good third-party house rule can work as well, provided that it has justifications/makes sense in what is going on.

Comment: I went through my books and cited the examples I could find of travel guidelines and encounters. Some of them are adventure-specific (like getting around in the Chicago snow), but many generalize well to other situations. _Darkest Hour_ has the most crunchy detail on travel arrangements. I wouldn't recommend buying any of these books _just_ for travel info, but they have lots of good bits and pieces.

Comment: I'll buy it. Looking over everything, it looks like you've pretty much exhausted most of the sources of information. Does Darkest Hour have any information on traveling legally?

Comment: Yes, the “Travel on the Fly” section specifically discusses commercial travel by air, sub-orbital, and train, including travel and luggage restrictions and the kinds of security scanners they use. For example, sub-orbitals do not allow anyone with a criminal SIN. There are also estimated costs and times for a Transatlantic trip by sub-orbital, commercial air, or smuggler.

Comment: That is an awesome answer and it deserves lots of votes.

Comment: Native American Nations Volume 1, one of SR1's combined adventure/sourcebooks involved a merry chase across the western half of North America, hitting four or five different countries. I can't remember the exact details, but it may have some material worth reading.